# How to import specific classes and object properties from an ontology in Protege?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I want to import some classes in Protege from different ontologies to my ontology. For example, I need the classes `foaf:Person`, `org:Site`, `vcard:Organization`, and many more.

I don't want to create them by myself (and modifying their IRI). When I did import the whole ontology (Schema.org, vCard, FOAF, …), I had many elements that I don't need.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175054/how-can-i-use-an-imported-ontology-in-protege#comment75366264_44175054). Is it sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @StanislavKralin thank you. It is not sufficient. I know how to import an ontology and to create a class with specific URI (like [http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person](http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person) ). I need to import just specific classes from an ontology. I don't need to add 100 classes to my ontology that I won't use.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread: http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/Import-specific-classes-of-another-ontology-td4662343.html ?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I tried to use it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> — Have you looked at this thread: protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/…
>
> — I tried to use it, but it didn't work.

There are subtle moments, especially on step 5.

1. Open your target ontology.

[image: target ontology]

2. Open the source ontology in the *same window*.

[image: source ontology]

3. Select *Refactor > Copy/move/delete axioms*:

[image: menu path]

4. Select axiom selection method.

[image: import options]

5. Select signature (i. e. a set  set of classes, properties etc.) to import. **Do not forget to press >> !**

[image: select signature]

6. Now you can preview axioms to be imported.

[image: axioms preview]

7. Select what you want to do:

[image: operation selectio]

8-9. Select your target ontology:

[image: existing vs new]

[image: target ontology]

10. Voila!

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, I discovered that my mistake was in step 2. I did open the ontologies in different windows, so I couldn't copy the classes.