# Why does the Protege GUI is showing deleted ontology terms?

Tags: ontology, protege, protege4

I am working with Epidemiology Ontology (EPO). I have downloaded the EPO ontology file from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/epidemiology-ontology/epo.owl). I need some limited terms from the ontology. Hence, I have deleted the terms that I do not need from the ontology file. The new file is available [here](https://github.com/shasan2/ontology). Next, I have loaded ontology file to Protege. However, still, Protege GUI is showing me the terms that I deleted. How can I get rid of the deleted terms (within the red box in the picture)? I only need terms in bold font. Thank you for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the import IRI in the original ontology?

If the IRI is unchanged, Protege will not load your modified ontology, but use the original ontology from the original IRI.

If the IRI has been changed but the logical IRI of the ontology (i.e., the one mentioned in the file) is the same, it is possible that Protege is using another copy of the original ontology.

The best course of action for this scenario is to ensure the modified ontology has a new logical IRI and is accessible at a different IRI, and then to use that IRI for importing. Also ensure you save and reload your importing ontology - imports resolution is carried out on loading, not on editing an existing import.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have changed EPO IRI. However, it is not working. I can see that EPO Direct Imports BFO (http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1). I think BFO causing the problem. Do you have any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: `independent_continuant` is defined in BFO, so you'll have to repeat the process on that ontology.

Comment: I think here is the answer of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205661/how-to-import-specific-classes-and-object-properties-from-an-ontology-in-protege