# Dependencies when copying entities from one ontology to the other on Protege

Tags: protege

I followed successfully this link: [How to import specific classes and object properties from an ontology in Protege?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205661/how-to-import-specific-classes-and-object-properties-from-an-ontology-in-protege). My question is, when I do this copy, does it **contain also the dependecies** of the entity I copied? Such as: Datatypes, Individuals, Classes, Object properties, Data properties? Or should I specifically include the dependencies of the class? Also when I visualize the ontology with OWLViz, because it is too huge, can I reduce the visualization in 2-stage only? Thanks...

Comment: Someone to give an idea? Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question shows how to copy axioms - so, the entities themselves will exist in the target ontology, but their definition (such as domains and ranges for the properties) are defined in separate axioms, which you will have to copy separately.

If you wish to copy all axioms referring to an entity, use the third option shown - axioms by reference. If you want to copy a whole module (as described here http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/research/modularity/ ) I'm not sure if Protege offers an option in the interface. It is certainly doable via code.