# Removing class annotations from owl ontology if included in a separated import

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have a "core" ontology (`core.owl`) in which I import a separated online ontology (`imports.owl`) using Protégé, ending up with a declaration in header

```
<Import>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...../imports.owl</Import>
```

Some classes are found both in `core.owl` and in `imports.owl`, to structure the final hierarchy. Unfortunately in both ontologies they also include annotations (such as `rdfs:label`) resulting in the duplication of a number of annotations in the final ontology, which is no good (for example, violates the OBO profile) and is what I'd like to solve.

Could anyone suggest methods to:

1. identify classes in both ontologies
2. remove all annotations those classes have in the core.owl ontology

Comment: Try manual import, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266590). Select "Axioms by type" on step 4, then _do not_ select "Annotation Axioms".

Comment: Thank you. I want to keep the importing method as it is in a separted owl file so the manual import would not do. I think that the process you pointed out would work, not in the importing or copying classes between ontologies, but rather by deleting axioms in `core.owl` *if* they are included in the `imports.owl`. The process form Refactor in Protégé is however all manual it seems (i.e. I need to manually select all classes for which deleting axioms); are there some ways to do it automatically (i.e. finding overlaps classes and then remove all annotation assertions for those classes)?

Comment: AFAIK, you do not need to select classes one-by-one after choosing "Axioms by Type".