# Protege import schema from schema.org

Tags: rdf, ontology, schema.org, protege, protege4

I have an ontology in Protege and I want to import a schema from schema.org.
How can I import a schema in an ontology. Let me give you my current example. I have a class Country in my ontology. I want to import the schema of a country from schema.org and have the same values for a country in my ontology. Here is the link from the schema: https://schema.org/Country. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an experimental OWL representation of the Schema.org type hierarchy [available to download](https://schema.org/docs/schemaorg.owl).

You can then import it in Protégé following the answer to this question:

[How to import specific classes and object properties from an ontology in Protege?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205661/how-to-import-specific-classes-and-object-properties-from-an-ontology-in-protege)